# Grab portions of a string when the string has dynamic variables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my database, I have a column with concatenated attributes like this:

> With color red; white beards; big round bellies

I need to select only big round bellies portion of the string. The issue is that "bellies" changes from record to record, so some will say "big round bellies" others will say "big round rear" or "big round thighs". There are too many nuances to code for each, but every attribute I need to capture begins with "big round".

Another issue is that "big round" is not always in the same position. Sometimes its in the middle, others in the beginning or end.

I've tried using `substring()` and `right()`, but because the last word is always different, I am having trouble executing this task...

Comment: What version of sqlserver?

Comment: I am using version 19

Comment: I'm impressed you've got a copy of SQL Server 19, @WhoDis . The latest public version is Version 15. We've not even heard or seen anything about the closed test release of Version 16 yet (which I assume would now be SQL Server 2022, as it's far too late for a 2021 release) You're 4 versions ahead of us!

Comment: You are right Larnu, I believe version 15 was released in 2019 that was my mistake. I am on version 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does not have very good string processing capabilities.  But you can empty the part before the string you want and then search for the end of the word after your phrase:

```
select left(v2.str, charindex(' ', replace(v2.str, ';', ' ') + ' ', 11) - 1)
from (values ('With color red; white beards; big round bellies'),
             ('With color red; big round bellies; white beards; ')
     ) v(str) cross apply
     (values (stuff(v.str, 1, charindex('big round ', str + 'big round') - 1, ''))) v2(str);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6758a9f0cb108a9289d59f7c704d9a61) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Just another option is to use `string_split()`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] varchar(50),[SomeCol] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'With color red; white beards; big round bellies')

Select A.ID
      ,B.* 
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply string_split(SomeCol,';') B
 Where B.value like '%Big round%'
```

**Returns**

```
ID  value
1    big round bellies
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that might look like an avalanche of string functions.

But the search pattern only needs to be filled in once.

And it also works on Sql Server 2012.

```
-- Sample data, using a table variable to test
declare @TestTable table (
 Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
 Col varchar(100) not null
);
insert into @TestTable values 
('With color red; Big Round Bellies; white beards'),
('With color red; white beards; Big Round Buttocks'),
('Big Round Mammaries; With color red; white beards');

-- Query
SELECT t.Id, a.BRB
FROM @TestTable t
OUTER APPLY(
     SELECT
       SUBSTRING(Col, 
         PATINDEX(pattern, Col), 
          ISNULL(NULLIF(
           CHARINDEX (';', Col, 
             PATINDEX(pattern, Col)),0), 
               LEN(Col))
                -PATINDEX(pattern, Col)
     ) AS BRB
     FROM (VALUES ('%big round %')) q(pattern)
) a;
```

**Returns:**

```
Id  BRB
1   Big Round Bellies
2   Big Round Buttock
3   Big Round Mammaries
```

A test on rextester [here](https://rextester.com/XGOJ32772)